# Why XBEE Sensor.py checks if self.__tracer.info():

Tags: python, xbee

I have been working around with a XBEE S2B Pro and a ConnectPort X4 and I have some questions about the drives xbee_sensor.py that can be found in folder 
C:\Program Files\Digi\python\DevTools-2.1\Dia\Dia_2.1.0\src\devices\xbee\xbee_devices\xbee_sensor.py

I have inserted some Traces in the drives to understand how it works.

In one of my traces, I could see that inside the 
def sample_indication(self, buf, addr):
the snippet

```
if self.__tracer.info():
    msg = []
    TRACER.critical('msg = [] %s', self.__tracer.info())
else:
    msg = None
    TRACER.critical('msg = None %s', self.__tracer.info())
```

returns `msg = None False`

As the subsequent code depends on the content of the msg

```
if msg is not None:
    msg.append("%d %s" % (temperature, scale))
```

the temperature is not appended in msg buffer, which leads to msg buffer is not filled with any data.

My question is: why is the test `self.__tracer.info()` done?

Answer (score 3):

Antonio, there is some undocumented behavior going on...

Looking at src/core/tracing.py on line 921, we have

```
def info(self, msg=None, *args):
    '''
    Send a message at the warning level.
    '''
    return self.log(LEVELS['INFO'], msg, *args)
```

and

```
def log(self, level, msg, *args):
    '''
    All other exposed Tracer methods call this method with their
    respective numerical values as the level argument.

    '''
    # basic cut-off
    if self.level > level:
        return False

    if msg == None:
        True
    ...
```

on line 866.

So

```
self.__tracer.info()
```

returns True if info level messages will be logged.